# Finding minimum distance in graph for path passing minimum three nodes and finishing with start node?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, pseudocode

I came across a problem to find optimal algorithm solving the issue: Finding minimum path in a graph from starting point to starting point(make a cycle) and visiting minimum three different nodes in the graph. For example if we have a graph `G(V,E)` with `V={a,b,c,d,e}` and edges `E={(a,b,16),(a,c,300),(a,d,1),(b,c,100),(b,e,15),(c,a,10),(e,c,20)}` the shortest distance will be 61 and it will visit `a->c->e->b->a`.

I think of using [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) for weighted graph, however I do not know how to implement the part for the constraint to visit minimum 3 nodes? It looks like the Hamiltonian cycle's problem but not using all the nodes but only part of them. Is this NP-complete problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way to implement this is the following:

1. precompute all-pair shortest paths (e.g. using [Floyd–Warshall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) or running Dijkstra for each possible start node)
2. for each tuple (a, b, c) of distinct nodes in the graph, consider the concatenation of shortest paths from a to b, b to c and c to a.
3. Report the minimum of all examined paths.

The runtime will be dominated by the second step, which has runtime O(n<sup>3</sup>). So no, the problem is not NP-hard, because the number of different nodes we have to visit is fixed (in this case, 3).